# A local domain $(R,\mathfrak m)$ which is not a field, then for its fraction field $K$ we have $\mathfrak m K=K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> If $(R,\mathfrak m)$ is a local domain which is  not a field, then for
> its fraction field $K$ we have $\mathfrak m K=K$.
>
> Amusingly, this proves that $K$ is not a finitely generated
> $R$-module.

I know this gives counterexample to NYK, my question is,

$1$.How can I get $\mathfrak m K=K$?

$2$.Why this proves that $K$ is not a finitely generated $R$-module?

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Actually, for any nonzero ideal $I$ of an integral domain (whether local or not), we have $IK=K$ since a field has only two ideals: $\{0\}$ and $K$.
2. If $K$ were a finitely generated $R$-module  ($R$ local), then, by Nakayama's lemma, $\; \mathfrak mK=K\implies K=\{0\}$. However, in a field $1\ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! How can we say IK＝K from the fact that field has only two ideals?

Comment: Every nonzero element has an inverse, hence $IK$ contains $1$.  Or, if you prefer, $IK$ is a nonzero ideal of $K$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\mathfrak{m}K \subset K$. Conversely, if $R$ is not a field then $\mathfrak{m} \neq 0$, and thus if you pick a nonzero $m \in \mathfrak{m}$, then $m$ acts invertibly on $K$ (because $m, m^{-1} \in K$). The reason that $K$ is not finitely generated then is because it would contradict Nakayama's lemma (maybe there's a more direct way of seeing this though), which in this case says that there should exist some nonzero $r \in R$ such that $rK = 0$ (which clearly can't happen).